# How I'm be able to query a multiple data in single model?

Tags: python, django, orm

How do I able to query if have three Car Models Car A, Car B andCar C and I wanted to switch this position base on their ordering? How do I able to perform that and what class based view should I use or just a function-based view?

Original DB : Car A --> Car B --> Car C

Alter DB : Car C --> Car B --> Car A

```
class CarColor(models.Model):
        colors = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        def __str__(self) -> str:
            return self.colors
    
    class Car(models.Model):
        car_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        car_model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        car_description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
        car_color = models.ForeignKey(CarColor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        car_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media', default='imageholder.png')
        date_manufactured = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            """ After creating or updating a Car, this function will be triggered and redirection using reverse"""
            return reverse("car_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
        
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['date_manufactured']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.car_name}'
```

Comment: Just use `ordering = ['-date_manufactured']` or `order_by('-date_manufactured')`?

Comment: I mean, how I may able to swap their position?

Comment: Can you explicitly describe what you want to achieve? Do you want to change ordering at queryset/list level, or in the database? I think overriding database order by recreating objects is not great idea since every override causes table incrementer uprise, so solution I gave you is best way to change order.

Comment: If I have to create a Car model, with this order Car A, Car B, Car C, Car D with respect to the ordering, How may I able to change the position of the Car C to Car A, it's like a pointer that holds the Car. This is how I visualize, original X = ['Car A', 'Car B', 'Car C', 'Car D'] and X[0], X[2] = X[2], [0], but I don't know how to implement using django